# Oradim for Oracle 18c not working on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, oracle

I installed Oracle 18c on a Windows Server 2016 VM with the following options: Software only, single instance database, Standard edition 2, Use virtual account.

When I try to run ORADIM command to create a database, the command never returns control to the prompt and I have to close it forcedly.

There aren't any error messages in oradim log file, the instance has been created as well as all the related Oracle Services.

The only error I was able to find in Windows Event Viewer is related to Oracle VSS Writer service:

"Volume Shadow Copy Service error: The process that hosts the writer with name Oracle Vss Writer - XXXX and ID {yyy} does not run under a user with sufficient access rights. Consider running this process under a local account which is either Local System, Administrator, Network Service or Local Service."

My understanding is that ORADIM command is not returning because the Vss service start fails, can someone confirm thiscould be the case? Is ORADIM command compatible with virtual user installation and what do I need to do to have it working?

Comment: Which account are you running the Oracle VSS Writer service as? (Apologies if that's implied from your list of installation options, I don't know the installer.)

Comment: The Oracle Vss service is created using a Windows Virtual Account (NT SERVICE\OracleVssWriterXXXX)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a test database then:

- Create a local or domain user for this Oracle instance such as Ora
- Add this user to the ora_dba group in the local windows groups and users
- Change the account the Oracle database and VSS Writer Service runs under (if they exist at this stage of the install) to this account
- Run OraDim again using this account

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm setting up the procedure to  install a production database so I need the installation to be as much automated as possible. The Oracle services don't exist before oradim command is launched.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm that oradim command freezes because of the Oracle Vss Service start failure: I launched the oradim command, as soon as the Oracle Vss Writer Service was created I modified the associated Log On user to LocalService and started the service, oradim command immediately returned control to the command window.

Thus I came up with this workaround in my installation script that seems to work, although I suppose there might be a better solution:

```
start oradim -new -sid %ORACLE_SID% -startmode manual

SET ORACLEVSS_NAME=OracleVssWriter%ORACLE_SID%

:VSSSRVCLOOP
SC QUERY %ORACLEVSS_NAME% > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO SVCCREATED
TIMEOUT 5 > NUL
GOTO VSSSRVCLOOP

:SVCCREATED
net stop %ORACLEVSS_NAME%
SC CONFIG %ORACLEVSS_NAME% obj= "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" password= ""
net start %ORACLEVSS_NAME%
```